# Nested html elements displaying unintended styling

Tags: php, html, css, styling

I have this code:

```
<?php $search =$_GET['search']?>

<p>Displaying search results for : <font style="font-weight:bolder;font-style:italic"><?php echo $search?></font></p>

<?php
$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_password='can't see my password..sorry';

mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
@mysql_select_db('galaxall');
?>

<!--the results-->

<p style="background-color:rgb(250,250,250)">
<div style="background-color:rgb(250,250,250);padding-bottom:3%;margin-right:20%">
<?php
$hello='hello everybody!!!';

$query="SELECT * FROM `galaxall_uploads` WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%' ";
if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query) )
{  
    while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run) )
    {
        echo $query_execute ['Title'].'<br>'.''.'<p style="background-color:blue;padding-bottom:5%">'.'<br>' ;
    }
} else {
    echo"Sorry, something went wrong...";
}
?> 
</p>
```

It is basically an SQL code to retrieve data from a database in an order. Each record when retrieved should be stylised (beautified using CSS). It works well except that the first and the last result are malformed. e.g. the first result is shown without any CSS styling (while the second,  third etc are ok) and the last is shown with CSS styling but the result itself is not there.

Screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the first 'ht' has no blue styling and the last has blue styling WITHOUT 'ht' (almost as if they separated from each other)

Comment: `<p><div>..` is not valid HTML. The browser is auto-correcting your bad code and resulting in something you didn't expect.

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol so i should remove one of them?

Comment: @ Niet the Dark Absol ..i've deleted one but it still didn't work

Comment: It also looks like you're outputting the `'Title'`, and *then* starting a blue `<p>` tag. Surely that should be the other way around?

Comment: `'can't see my password..sorry';` is that part of your actual working code? It's showing a parse error here.

Comment: @ Funk Forty Niner no...no its not.I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `mysql_` functions [are deprecated from php5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).
- I will recommend, while upgrading to `mysqli`, that you learn about object-oriented syntax because it is less verbose than procedural syntax.
- It is simple to nominate your targeted database while connecting, so roll that all into one line.
- You are building a database query with user-supplied data, so a prepared statement is called for.  When there is no submitted value you *could* avoid a prepared statement, but to reduce code complexity, I'm writing a prepared statement to handle all occurrences.
- When designing your `SELECT` clause, if you don't need all of the columns for your task, only request the columns that you will use.
- You should try to avoid inline styling, by writing style declarations in the `<head>` tag or even in a separate file.  This will improve the overall readability and maintainability of your code.
- Writing error checks into your code will be immensely helpful when you need to debug your work -- so get into the habit of doing it all of the time.  As a matter of security, never show exact error details to your users.
- `$query_execute` is not a great choice for a variable that contains data from a resultset row.  It doesn't "execute" anything, so try not to confuse yourself and future code readers (humans) with such terminology.
- As for you specific html issue, try to eliminate all unnecessary DOM elements (tags) in your output.  It seems that you only need one containing `div` for your `p` elements.

Untested Code:

```
echo "<div style=\"background-color:rgb(250,250,250); padding-bottom:3%; margin-right:20%\">";
if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "galaxall")) {
    echo "<font style=\"color:red;\">Database Connection Error</font>"; // don't show this to the public--> $conn->connect_error;
} else {
    if (!isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $search = "";
        echo "<p>No search keyword received.  Showing all rows<p>";
    } else {
        $search = strip_tags($_GET['search']);  // perform whatever sanitizing/filtering/preparation techniques in this line
        echo "<p>Displaying search results for: <font style=\"font-weight:bolder; font-style:italic\">$search</font></p>";
    }
    if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Title FROM galaxall_uploads WHERE Title LIKE ? ORDER BY Title")) {
        echo "<font style=\"color:red;\">Prepare Syntax Error</font>"; // don't show this to the public--> $conn->error;
    } else {
        if (!$stmt->bind_param("s", "%$search%") || !$stmt->execute() || !$result = $stmt->get_result()) {
            echo "<font style=\"color:red;\">Statement Error</font>"; // don't show this to the public--> $stmt->error;
        } elseif (!$result->num_rows){
            echo "<p>No matches in the database for \"$search\"</p>";
        } else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<p style=\"background-color:blue; padding-bottom:5%\">{$row['Title']}</p>";
            }
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't using `LIKE` in my query.

Answer (score -1):

Its because you are doing it wrong. try the following

```
while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run) )
    {
        echo '<p style="background-color:blue;padding-bottom:5%">'.$query_execute ['Title'].'</p><br>' ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work...maybe you can try showing me the whole new code?

Comment: You are being too lazy man. Common just copy the loop code and replace it with yours. you give me a downvote for this

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `div` element inside a `p` element and also your code to print databse results has some wrong so i suggest this:-

```
<!--the results-->

<div style="background-color:rgb(250,250,250);padding-bottom:3%;margin-right:20%">
<?php
$hello='hello everybody!!!';

$query="SELECT * FROM `galaxall_uploads` WHERE Title LIKE '%$search%' ";
if($is_query_run=mysql_query($query) )
{


    while($query_execute=mysql_fetch_assoc($is_query_run) )
    {

        echo '<p style="background-color:blue;padding-bottom:5%">'.$query_execute ['Title'].'</p><br/>' ;


    }

}

else
{
    echo"Sorry, something went wrong...";
}


?> 
</div>
```